# how to access my wallet.dat

Tags: wallet

I setup a Bitcoin many years ago. I dont remember if I bought anything.
I found on my old computer a folder : Bitcoin under Appdata/Roaming ...and these files and Folders:
 BLocks
 Chainstate 
.Lock
dblog
debug.log
peers.dat
wallet.dat

Was those files installed my a program of some sort ?
How can I get Access to those files to see if there are some coins in there at all ?:)
Or can I just delete all of those files ?

-

Comment: If you are completly new to the world of bitcoin, I recommend first to do a backup of these files (or better two or three), and then install a normal bitcoin client. Then learn the basics, and later on you can try to bring back the wallet.dat file into a folder, redirect your bitcoin client to this folder, and see if something is in there.

Answer (score 1):

Those files are created by Bitcoin Core software. The important one is wallet.dat, do not delete it. You can download and run bitcoin core to open the wallet, but that will probably take a long time to sync. You could open it and dumpwallet, and then check each address on a block explorer or import them into a different wallet like electrum

Answer (score 0):

you could also dump it with [pywallet](https://github.com/jackjack-jj/pywallet) without having to install and run Bitcoin Core or any other bitcoin client, and check the addresses as [MeshCollider](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/51948/meshcollider) said.